# How can I split this equation?

Tags: spacing, equations, environments

Does anyone know how to split this equation in two lines?

```
\begin{equation*}

\iint_S \eta = \iint_S \left[F(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} + G(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}+H(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right]

\end{equation*}
```

I would like the equation to look like this

```
\begin{equation*}

 \iint_S \eta = \iint_S \left[F(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} + G(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}+

H(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right]

\end{equation*}
```

by adding a linebreak or whatever necessary right at the +H(x(u,v)...

Please, bear in mind that I'm pretty new to latex

[image: This is a screenshot of my document]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to *TeX.SX*.  You must learn to write a question using our format rules [view here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: The `split` environment may work for this. See [Herbert Voß, Math mode](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf), specifically equation II-86 on p.55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `multline*`  environment, as there's to align naturally:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nomarginpar,  showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\iint_S \eta = \iint_S \left[F(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right. \\\left.{} + G(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}+ H(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right]
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \iint_S \eta  = \iint_S \Bigl[& F(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} 
  +  G(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\\
  &  + H(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \Bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose this alternative.

```
    \begin{equation*}
      \begin{split}  
    \iint_S \eta =& \iint_S \Bigl\{F(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} + G(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))  \frac{\partial(x,y)} \partial(u,v)}+
     \\ 
    &H(x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v)) \ \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \Bigr\} 
    \end{split}
   \end{equation*}
```